# How should I handle warnings in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling

In my Symfony project I'm using a library for creating ssh connections. In my script I'll try to connect using different ports (an array of prots). In case it can't connect using one port it will try with the next one (because we use different ports in different servers, not a hacking or port scan thing).

The third party library I'm using throws an [`user notice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php) when it can't connect to a server. So if the correct port for the connection is the second one, it will first throw a `user notice` saying it couldn't connect and then it will connect with the second one.

When I run muy Symfony project in `prod` environment everything looks ok (as `user notice` messages are disabled), but in `dev` environmet the Symfony´s `ErrorHandler` turns this messages into `Exceptions` terminating the code execution.

So far I have some alternatives, but I don't like any of them:

1. Using `error_reporting()` to hide this kind of messages... but useful information will be lost.
2. Using the @ operator to hide the warning for that function...  but everyone hates @.
3. Turning off debug in Symfony's `dev` environment... but useful information will be lost.
4. Use `try` `catch` to handling the Exception... but why? there will be no Exception in production.

What is the best alternative?

Comment: Use a different library?  Or maybe check the code and see if it supports a config option to disable the warning.  Very strange for a modern library to not have anticipated your use case.

Comment: @Cerad thanks for teh advise. But regarding the library I use, how should I proceed when a warnign is thrown in the dev environment in Symfony?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the default Symfony error handling action to your own need by writing an EventListener that listens to kernel.exception. Read on:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#working-with-the-kernel-exception-event